# Speed Up Initial Execution of Python Command Line App

Tags: python, command-line

I've prototyped a command line application for quick note-taking using Python and [argparse](http://docs.python.org/library/argparse.html#module-argparse).  Right now it basically just launches Vim and then shoves the buffer into a SQLite database.

The problem is, loading Python is *slow* on both of my machines (~2/3GHz Intel Core 2 Duos) and the most basic functionality (printing a help menu on startup) can take over a second.  I know my code is fine because Python is perfectly fast and the interactive mode is snappy once Python loads, but I can mimic my annoyance with a simple Hello Word:

```
$ time python -c "print 'hello world'"
hello world
real    0m0.669s
user    0m0.070s
sys     0m0.041s
```

Of course, the problem is not unique to Python:

```
$ time erl -noshell -eval 'io:fwrite("Hello, World!\n"), init:stop().'
Hello, World!
real    0m2.824s
user    0m0.253s
sys     0m0.104s
```

My question is:  **How can I speed up the initial execution of a Python application?**  I want my program to feel like `git` or `wc`.

**System:** I encounter this problem with python2.6 on OS X 10.6.8 and with python2.7 on OS X 10.7.2.

Note: Subsequent executions of `python` (and `erl`) are much faster, but I'm already dogfooding this program and I want it to be truly snappy.

**Update:** I've tried running [pypy](http://pypy.org/) and find it has similar initial load time to python2.6 and 2.7 on both of my systems (~.5 seconds on initial load), half the performance on subsequent calls compared to python2.6 on OS X 10.6.8 (~.08s for pypy, ~.35s for 2.6), and similar performance on subsequent calls compared to python2.7 on OS X 10.7.2 (~.08s for pypy *and* python2.7).

**Update 2:** Output from dr jimbob's suggestion (this seems to trim the initial load time by 2/3) -

```
$ python -vSEc "print 'hello world'"
# installing zipimport hook
import zipimport # builtin
# installed zipimport hook
import encodings # directory /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/encodings
# /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/encodings/__init__.pyc matches /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/encodings/__init__.py
import encodings # precompiled from /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/encodings/__init__.pyc
# /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/codecs.pyc matches /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/codecs.py
import codecs # precompiled from /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/codecs.pyc
import _codecs # builtin
# /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/encodings/aliases.pyc matches /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/encodings/aliases.py
import encodings.aliases # precompiled from /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/encodings/aliases.pyc
# /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/encodings/utf_8.pyc matches /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/encodings/utf_8.py
import encodings.utf_8 # precompiled from /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/encodings/utf_8.pyc
Python 2.6.1 (r261:67515, Jun 24 2010, 21:47:49) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5646)] on darwin
hello world
# clear __builtin__._
# clear sys.path
# clear sys.argv
# clear sys.ps1
# clear sys.ps2
# clear sys.exitfunc
# clear sys.exc_type
# clear sys.exc_value
# clear sys.exc_traceback
# clear sys.last_type
# clear sys.last_value
# clear sys.last_traceback
# clear sys.path_hooks
# clear sys.path_importer_cache
# clear sys.meta_path
# clear sys.flags
# clear sys.float_info
# restore sys.stdin
# restore sys.stdout
# restore sys.stderr
# cleanup __main__
# cleanup[1] zipimport
# cleanup[1] _codecs
# cleanup[1] signal
# cleanup[1] encodings
# cleanup[1] encodings.utf_8
# cleanup[1] encodings.aliases
# cleanup[1] exceptions
# cleanup[1] _warnings
# cleanup[1] codecs
# cleanup sys
# cleanup __builtin__
# cleanup ints: 3 unfreed ints
# cleanup floats

real    0m0.267s
user    0m0.009s
sys     0m0.043s
```

Comment: Which python version is that? What platform? On Fedora I get 0.029s on the first run. Do you have many paths in your `$PATH`, is python in one of the first paths?

Comment: Depending on your situation, simply running a `nop` script in your `.bashrc` file or similar might solve your problem.  Not exactly a "good solution", however.

Comment: Funny; on my core 2 duo core (E8400) 3GHz (operating at 2GHz) machine, I'm getting `time python -c "print 'hello world'"` to be 0.018s real.

Comment: And your user and sys times do not add up to real time anywhere close. Do you have enough free memory?

Comment: @MaximYegorushkin 2.6 on OS X 10.6.8 or 2.7 on OS X 10.7.2.

Comment: @MaximYegorushkin `echo $PATH -- 
/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11/bin:/Users/codyhess/bin`, `which python -- /usr/bin/python` and 718MB free memory.

Comment: @drjimbob Are you running OS X?  I don't have a non-Mac to test this on.

Comment: I once read that you can greatly reduce startup time by rewriting import machinery and making it lazy - it's supposed to be done in Mercurial. I can't find the link now and never tried it myself, though. Mercurial implementation: http://selenic.com/repo/hg/file/tip/mercurial/demandimport.py

Comment: @CodyHess - The above quote was linux (ubuntu).  On a mac (lion), python2.7.1 gave me `0.032ms (real)`, but then python2.6 was slow (0.370s real/0.011s user/0.043s sys).  Now, that I look at it I likely had run python on my machine previously; and I was finding say running other python versions (3.1/3.2) that likely weren't running on linux were slower (0.155s real).

Comment: I tried pypy which seemed to be very snappy on linux (0.030 ms); but was quite slow (1.260s) when I installed it and ran on a mac the first time.

Comment: Running your cmd on a freshly booted linux mint vm, I get times of: real 0.058s user 0.040s sys 0.010s so I'm not quite sure what's wrong with your times.

Comment: You can save a small amount of time by making sure the Python script is bytecompiled (.pyc rather than .py) -- `import` it from another script and that will happen automatically.

Comment: Can you try running `python -vSEc "print 'hello world'"` (-v to print a message on each module; `-S` to disable `import site`, `-E` to ignore environment variables).  (I can't reboot the mac as someone is using it).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make use of a similar technique used by the infamous "Microsoft Office Quick Start" or the "Java Quick Start" and, IIRC even the "Adobe Fast-something"...

The trick is to try and keep all the libraries of the program in the disk cache, all the time.

You can get it with a simple crontab command, programmed to be run once each hour. The exact details will depend on your system, but should work with something like:

```
$ crontab -e
0 * * * * python -c 'pass'
```

Although to me more effective you should write a simple Python script that imports all the modules your program is using and then just ends.

Comment: +1 This will probably end up being the solution, but I'm going to ponder it for another day or two.  (Actually, the solution is most likely to be ignoring the problem and getting a better computer :-p)

Comment: @CodyHess Good job proving Moore's law (observation) correct :P