# Python script first execution takes seconds

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I have a fresh Mac with High Sierra version 10.13.6. Default installed python has version:

```
➜  ~ python --version
Python 2.7.10
```

I installed python 3 with:

```
➜  ~ brew install python
```

So I get:

```
➜  ~ python3 --version
Python 3.7.0
```

With both versions of python, when I run a very simple script like this:
`print("this is the text")` for the first time, the execution is very slow:

```
➜  ~ time python3 test.py
this is the text
python3 test.py  0.02s user 0.02s system 1% cpu 2.945 total
```

Subsequent executions are much faster:

```
➜  ~ time python3 test.py
this is the text
python3 test.py  0.03s user 0.02s system 70% cpu 0.071 total
```

Whenever I change something in the script and re-run it, the first execution is very slow. This happens with both versions of python. I tried the same steps on ubuntu and there is no evidence of this problem.

What am I missing? How could I make the also the first execution run in a reasonable time?

Comment: This can happen with other programs on Mac, not just with python.  See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7812115/speed-up-initial-execution-of-python-command-line-app and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42986408/bash-scripts-extremely-slow-to-start-on-osx/44379589

Comment: Tried both, but the problem is still there